# Couldn't perform click, button not found in: 'click on "OBFormFieldSelectInputRequired"'

Tags: testrigor

Recently, I registered with Testrigor and am using its Free version. We need to test dynamic web applications in Testrigor, then we write scripts for the same. In our Application 3 field use same class selector ,so when i used class in script for enter value in that class but that time Test rigor entered value in another field because of same class,i was try to resolve issue using Name And id Locator but Issue not Solved.
I am getting the following error in one field .
Couldn't perform click, button not found in: 'click on "OBFormFieldSelectInputRequired"'.
Please check attached screenshot.

[image: 1]

I'm Tried with Name And Id locator

Answer (score 0):

You can target fields with the same name using relative locations. Using your picture as a reference, let's say that all the fields with a dropdown arrow on the right side are called the same thing. You can say `click "inputName" below "labelName"` If that doesn't work, it's probably because the label is small and the field is long. See image: [image]

The way to handle this is using overlap, which is in testRigor documentation. You can say the following:

`click "inputName" with at least "1" percent overlap below "labelName"`

Alternatively, if the input field is tagged as  and/or is named the same as the label, you can say the following:

`click input "labelName"``
That should associate the label with the input, even if the name is not the same.